Не определяется POST запрос
Есть страница login.html, которая содержит в себе форму логина, основанную на POST запросе
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login – Admin Portal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="header-text">Login</h1>
<div class="input-container">
    <form id="loginForm" action="verify_login.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" class="login" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" required><br><br>
        <input type="password" class="login" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br><br>
        <input type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
    </form>
</div>

<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="/js/login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

И при нажатии кнопки переводит на verify_login.php, который должен проверить данные в MySQL
<?php
require_once('./mysql/mysql.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "Welcome, $username!";
} else {
    echo "Wrong login or password!";
    echo "SQL запрос: $sql<br>";
    echo "Параметры: username = $username, password = $password<br>";
}

$stmt->close();

$conn->close();
?>

Даже с верными данными страница возвращает "Wrong login or password!", попытался выловить какие данные проверяются - получил пустые username и password, хотя на login.html они заполняются. Собственно, нужно, чтобы данные проверялись.

По идее все должно работать. Что такое /js/login.js и зачем он здесь? Если сделать форму вообще без всяких яваскриптов, то данные передаются?

На будущее: сам код неплохой, но пароль надо хэшировать.

Если отправка значений идёт через JS, а на сервере значения пустые, то надо смотреть именно в js что не так. Что отправляется, как получают значения и т.д.

login.js - пустой файл, созданный на будущее для продолжения работы с JS, без подключения к /js/login.js аналогично не передаются никакие данные, за совет с хэшированием спасибо!

Какой сервер используется? Это только в этой форме? В других данные передаются? Сделайте другую форму, попроще, без всех этих рюшечек и бантиков "на вырост". Сделайте var_dump($_POST). Сделайте метод get. В адресной строке будут данные? Выведите var_dump($_GET). выведите значение ini_get('variables_order');

Плюс для вопроса "не определяется POST запрос" здесь слишком много кода. Должен быть только вывод полученных через форму данных. программист всегда должен решать только одну задачу в единицу времени. Иначе он запутается сам и запутает других.

Все стоит на ОпенСервере, пробовал ставить на бегет - всё тоже самое, попробовал сейчас на чистом сайте без стилей, подключений к файлам стилей и js - всё работает, как с GET, так и с POST, убрал подключение к js файлам на основном сайте - аналогично всё работает, теперь понятно в чём была ошибка, спасибо!
